# Remap tablet volume key in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am trying to write a program for Windows 10 in UWP/Windows 8 (Universal) app in C# which will remap tablet's volume button to Screen Brightness level setter.

So far, I searched for events which may fire whenever window's master volume level changes. But could not found any useful links. Or is there any Windows C++ function to call for such purpose?

I was able to change the brightness level with C++'s **SetDeviceGammaRamp** function. I was wondering to call this function on Windows volume change event